# yii2: mongodb aggregate clause returns internal server error

Tags: mongodb, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

my database is mongodb. I am using following query with Yii2 for grouping.

```
$query->select([])
      ->from('networklog')
      ->aggregate([
          [
              '$group' => [
                  '_id' => '$userid', 'date' => [ '$max' => '$datetime' ]
              ]
          ],
          [ '$sort' => [ 'date'=>'1' ]],
       ]);

$rows = $query->all();
```

In mongodb i used following query and it works.

```
db.networklog.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$userid", date: { $max: "$datetime" } } },
    { $sort: { date:1 } },
])
```

how to write same query in yii2 for desired result?

Answer (score 0):

yii2 has the following syntax for using aggregation of Mongo:

```
    $collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('your_mongo_collection');

    $data = $collection->aggregate(
    [
        '$match' => [
            'name' => $name,
        ]
    ], [
        '$group' => [
            '_id' => '_id',
            'count' => [
                '$sum' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```